# Access all registry keys as Administrator (permission exception)

Tags: windows-7, permissions, registry

I am traversing the registry on Windows 7 from C#. When opening certain subkeys, I get a SecurityException:

`Requested registry access is not allowed.`

An example is "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer".

I've searched similar questions and found suggestions to run Visual Studio with Administrator privileges. I tried that and also tried running the build as Administrator, but I still get SecurityExceptions.

Is there a way to get full access to the registry from C#?

Comment: Any luck with this?  Did the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `runas`, for reaources I suggest you to take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation).